# Trouble when reverse and display string in assembly

Tags: assembly, dos, masm, x86-16

here is my code:

```
model small
stack 100h

.data
string1 db "Khoa$"
string2 db 4 dup(?)
count dw 4
.code
begin:  
mov ax,@data
mov ds,ax
mov es,ax
mov cx,count
mov si,0
mov di,0
add di,count
dec di

again:  mov al,string1[si]
mov string2[di],al
inc si
dec di
loop again

mov ah,9
lea dx,string1
int 21h

end begin
```

in this part

```
mov ah,9
lea dx,string1
int 21h
```

when i try to display string1 to console, it's ok.
but no result with string2.

i'm new to assembly. Please help!

Comment: What do you mean by 'no result'? - also, you're actually printing `string1` in both places, was that just  a copy/paste error? Finally, your `string2` should be 5 bytes and include an end marker as well.

Answer (score 0):

Although this is homework, this is a reasonable attempt at a solution. I don't know what assembler you are using - it looks like *MASM* but I'm unsure how these 2 lines could assemble without a syntax error:

```
model small
stack 100h
```

I think this should be (note the *periods* in front as they are assembler directives):

```
.model small
.stack 100h
```

`string1` is initially 5 characters long including the `$` to terminate the string. When using *int 21h/ah 9* strings need to be terminated with `$` or it will continue to print junk beyond the end of your string. With that in mind your output buffer should be long enough to hold 5 characters including the `$`
so `string2` should be defined as:

```
string2 db 5 dup(?)
```

The primary problem in your code is terminating the string with a `$`. One way would be to place the `$` in the last position of the array when you set up the `si` and `di` registers initially:

```
mov si,0
mov di,0
add di,count
mov string2[di],'$'   ; Put string terminator in last position
dec di
```

Also note:

```
mov di,0
add di,count
```

Could be written simply as:

```
mov di, count
```

If you are using *MASM*, to gracefully exit your 16 bit program you might want to put a `.exit` directive just before your end statement:

```
.exit
end begin
```