# Reverse string (irvine)

Tags: assembly, x86, reverse, masm, irvine32

I am supposed to take a string that is at least 50 characters long using letter numbers and symbols and reverse it in assembler for a class. He gave us this piece of code:

```
string1 BYTE "abcdefghijklmnopqurstuvwxyz",10,13,0
string2 BYTE 50 DUP(?),10,13,0
```

We are also not allowed to us stacks or string functions.

I think I get the logic to use but I need help with the syntax for it. I think we are supposed to get the number of characters in the string and then using loops we reverse them.

Here is what I have so far but I am getting error 2022 in line 15 saying that operands must be the same size.

```
 TITLE masm Template                        (main.asm)
; Description:reserve string code
; 
; Revision date:4/3/16

INCLUDE Irvine32.inc
.data
string1 BYTE "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwsyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWSYZ123!@#",10,13,0
string2 BYTE 58 DUP(?),10,13,0
count dw 13
.code

main PROC
    mov ax, @data
    mov ds,ax
    mov es,ax
    mov cx,count ;cx=58
    mov sI,0
    mov di,0
    add di,count ;
    dec di

again: mov al,string1[si]
    mov string2[di],al;
    inc si
    dec di
    loop again
    call WriteString


    exit
main ENDP
```

We are using visual studio 2013 for compiling

[here is the video I used to get this far](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aOheFNXcIRI)

Comment: What is your actual question?  All you've said is that you don't know the syntax for the programming language you want to use.  Do [the NASM docs](http://www.nasm.us/doc/nasmdoc3.html#section-3.1) help?  You haven't said what assembler you're using, either.  Err, I guess Irvine is specifically MASM.  I forget if the [x86 tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info) has links to MASM docs, but it does have some tutorials.

Comment: "error 2022 in line 15" and nothing more? What compiler is that?

Comment: Possibly you need to change `mov ax, string1` into `mov ax, offset string1`.

Comment: `mov ax, offset string1` did not work and gave same error.

Comment: You need to use 32 bit registers for addressing since you code for 32 bit. That looks like some 16 bit code you copied from somewhere...

Comment: The code you presented shares some awful similarities to the 16-bit DOS code in this Stackoverflow question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32568014/trouble-when-reverse-and-display-string-in-assembly/32569487  . You aren't going to get far using someone else's 16-bit DOS code and compiling as 32-bit code using Irvine32.